# How can methane hydrates mining affect earth other than it’s climate?

Tags: environment

My story take place in 200 years forward post apocalypstic war between two faction which the (villain) protagonist side have massive fuel economy disadvantages compare to their enemy who mastered bio technology and agriculture like algae and crops for biofuel on top of having biofuel productions of protagonist’s side get sabotaged in biological warfare multiple times. Leaving them with small biofuel economy along with only nuclear isomer ,petroleum , coal oil,and methane hydrate which is their only field their enemy can’t contest with .

Let’s just say that the population from protagonist’s side are terminally infected cyborg in Orwellian states that’s too half dead to care about pollution and global warming, in fact they even radiate their mining site out of every organism. But I want to know if there’s any problem other than global warming when mining methane ice.

Comment: Nuclear isomers? Why is the other faction even a threat? An economy with high density, portable nuclear energy doesn't need methane hydrates or any biofuels at all...They can even synthesize hydrocarbons for petrochemicals from the air and water.

Answer (score 4):

### Tsunamis

When you mine methane ice in deep sea, you change the equilibrium between methane and water inside the sediments. Adding water inside the sediments of ocean floor can provoke landslips. and landslips under water can provoke tsunamis.

Therefore, mining methane ice close from the coast can provoke tsunamis and damage your coast.

And keep in mind that a big part of methane hydrates are near the coasts

[image: methane ice map]